# Display Image Name in Slide Show

Tags: php, jquery

I have been learning to use a slideshow code I saw on a website somewhere. Although I have managed to get it working with the images showing well, but I can't figure out how to show the image name in another table alongside the images when the slide changes.

I have [provided the code here](http://pastebin.com/XFkA2wPe). so I need your help. What I'm looking for s that whenever the slideshow changes with another picture, I want the picture name displayed next to it.

Thanks for your asisstance.

**Update** - Here's the updated code based on Gilly3's suggestion, but I'm still confused on how to get the name displayed

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
<title>JQuery Cycle Plugin - Pager Demo with Prev/Next Controls</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../jq.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="cycle.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/chili-1.7.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
#main { margin: 20px }
#nav { margin: 10px; position: relative }
#nav li { float: left; list-style: none}
#nav a { margin: 5px; padding: 3px 5px; border: 1px solid #ccc; background: #fc0; text-decoration: none }
#nav li.activeSlide a { background: #faa; color: black }
#nav a:focus { outline: none; }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#slideshow').cycle({
          prev:    '.prev', // Setup prev links
          next:    '.next', // Setup next links
          pager:   '.nav',       // Setup pager navs

         before: function () {
        $("#name").text(this.alt);
    }
     }); 
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
#left, #slideshow, #right { float: left; width: 200px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- left nav bar -->
<div id="left">
    <a href="#"><span class="prev">Prev</span></a> 
    <a href="#"><span class="next">Next</span></a>

    <ul class="nav"></ul>
</div>

<!-- slideshow -->
<div id="slideshow">

 <?php
                 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")or die("cannot connect");
                 mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");

                 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people") or die(mysql_error());
                 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )){
                 echo "<img src=\"http://localhost:8080/about/images/".$info['photo'] . "\" alt=\"".$info['name'] ."\"/>";
  }
?>

</div>

<div id="name">
HELP ME PRINT THE NAME HERE
</div>
<!-- right nav bar -->
<div id="right">
    <a href="#"><span class="prev">Prev</span></a> 
    <a href="#"><span class="next">Next</span></a>
    <ul class="nav"></ul>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Provide the code *here*, and a live demo would be useful (perhaps at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us to play with, and see what you're working with.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either of the `before` or `after` events, depending on when you want the name to change.

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({
    prev: '.prev',
    next: '.next',
    pager: '.nav',
    before: function () {
        $("#name").text(this.alt);
    }
});
```

You'll need to populate `alt` with the name in your php.  If you don't want to add a tooltip, also add `title=""`.

```
echo "<img src=\"http://localhost:8080/people/uploads/".$info['pic'] . "\" alt=\"".$info['name'] . "\" title=\"\" />";
```

Comment: Thanks Gilly3 for your help. I'm new to all these and have no idea what before or after is :( Would you mind showing me how to use it? I greatly appreciate your assistance.

Comment: @Julie - Set the `before` or `after` property in your call to `.cycle()` as I have done in the first code example in my answer.  That's all you have to do.  The function you provide will be called either before or after each image transition.  It is in this function that you would set the name of the image.

Comment: Thanks again Gilly3, I'm a bit lost so I've posted the updated code above. But nothing seems to be displaying apart from the images. The names are not showing in the 'name' div :(

Comment: @Julie - You are missing the comma after `pager: '.nav'`.

Comment: You are a god send. It's now working like a charm. You've been great through out - answering my questions. I appreciate it a lot. God bless you. Have a great day! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think should work:

Add a 'data-name' attribute to each image. Something like:

```
echo "<img src='http://localhost:8080/people/uploads/".$info['pic']."' data-name='".$info['name']."'/>";
```

In the jquery.cycle plugin set an option for the 'onPrevNextEvent'. Probably something like:

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({
    prev:    '.prev',
    next:    '.next',
    pager:   '.nav',
    onPrevNextEvent:   function(isNext, zeroBasedSlideIndex, slideElement){
        var name = slideElement.data('name');
        $("#name").html(name);
    }
});
```

Hope that helps.

Bob